# Add picture to div with jQuery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I want to click on div with `btnGenerate` class and that is supposed to add an image to div with `card1` class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="btnGenerate">
    <p class="generate">Generate team</p>
</div>
<div class="card1"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnGenerate').click(function () {
        $('.card1').prepend('<img class="card" src="card1">');
    });
});
```

## Problem

When I click on `.btnGenerate` it doesn't add an image to my `.card1`. So I want it to add my image to the class

Comment: what is your question? what is your problem?

Comment: When I click on my class btnGenerate it doesn't add an image to my card1 class. So I want it to add my image to the class.

Comment: Your code work fine you should just add the right image `src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks OK. You just need to add the proper image path to `src` of `img` element :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnGenerate').click(function () {
        $('.card1').prepend('<img class="card" src="http://placehold.it/100x50/ff7878">');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btnGenerate">
    <p class="generate">Generate team</p>
</div>
<div class="card1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked with your image. I looked trough my code once again and I had written crad1.png instead of card1.png. Coding is difficult with dyslexia, haha. :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just not add any extensions to link or path problems
for example that works well :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnGenerate').click(function() {
    $('.card1').prepend('<img class="card" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btnGenerate">
  <p class="generate">Generate team</p>
</div>

<div class="card1"></div>
```